# Shortest way to retrieve an element from a Doctrine ArrayCollection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm looking for the shortest way to retrieve an element from a Doctrine `ArrayCollection` by it's Id. Currently I'm doing something like this (which obviously is a bit clunky):

```
function public getAddressById( $customer, $addressId )
{
   $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();

   foreach( $addresses as $address )
   {
      if( $address->getId() == $addressId )
      {
         return $address;
      }
   }

   return NULL;
}
```

Is there a shorter way (syntax wise) to retrieve an element by it's Id from a Doctrine `ArrayCollection`?

Comment: I am guessing from what you have posted that you are using a class for $customer? and created functions for getAddresses() and this returns a class for each $address which has a function of getId()? would it not be easier to add a function to the $customer which is getAddress( $id ) and assuming it is coming from a DB could just add a where clause to the same sql as getAddresses()? This would save the need to cycle each address? and would end up being something like return ( $address = $customer->getAddress( $addressId ) )? $address : null;

Comment: Hi, these are basic Doctrine conventions. `$customer` is an entity, and no, I don't add logic to my entities, or at least I try not to and keep my entities as POPO as much as possible. The method you see above is part of the `CustomerModel` that implements all logic regarding customers.